# Are minors allowed to offer korbanot or meal offerings

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban, minor-katan-child, age, mincha-meal-offering

According to Halacha, when the temple in Jerusalem is standing, can minor Jews (under bar mitzvah age) offer meal offerings or korbanot? Or can they only come from Jews over bar mitzvah age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Minor Kohanim cannot offer *korbanot*.** There is a dispute in the gemara ([Chulin 24b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.24b.8?lang=bi)) as to the minimum age and the reason for it. The Sages further dispute whether the service of a Kohen aged 13-20 is valid after the fact or invalid.

The Rambam writes up the halacha as follows ([MT Klei Hamikdash 5:15](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1008230/jewish/Klei-Hamikdash-Chapter-5.htm))

> As soon as a priest matures and attains majority, he is fit to serve
> in the Temple. **Nevertheless, his priestly brethren would not allow him
> to serve in the Temple until he reached the age of 20**.

Two reasons I saw for this are that

- at age 20, he can be expected to be more mature and less likely to commit an error that would disqualify a sacrifice (R Elyahu Touger)
- it was demeaning to the Kohanim to have a youth serve with them (Meiri).

Answer (score 0):

The Kohen who performs the offering would have to be above bar mitzva.

Regarding the customer who brings the thing for the Kohen to offer up, there wasn't anyone checking that the offering was actually required of the customer. When the Moshiach comes, that would be a good business to set up: Korban Konsultant.

If the minor puts his hands on the animal and confesses sins, it's not the Kohen's job to argue that he didn't do a sin. In fact, doing so could cause more problems. If the animal was designated for a korban and the kohen decides not to bring it, that animal would have to be monitored, forever, until it died naturally, to ensure nobody benefits from it.

Comment: Citing your sources would improve your answer.

Comment: "there wasn't anyone checking that the offering was actually required"? Sure there was; it's called the בית דין של כהנים. For example, suppose a person was bringing a chatas, they'd tell him whether in fact he's obligated to bring it (because if not, then you've got חולין בעזרה).

Comment: Can I get a source for that? And do all korbanot brought by individuals have to go through them? Does the kohen on the slaughtering floor do any judgment once the animal has been designated?